dnsmasq not block google.com subdomains
dnsmasq installed on my server and has the following configuration:
no-hosts
no-resolv 

server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
server=/google.com/127.0.0.1
address=/google.com/127.0.0.1
server=/*.google.com/#



but when I try to check with the utility DIG I get the following response:
`
dig @127.0.0.1 mail.google.com
mail.google.com.        0       IN      A       127.0.0.1
dig @127.0.0.1 google.com`
google.com.             0       IN      A       127.0.0.1
why does mail.google.com it output 127.0.0.1 if there is a rule server=/*.google.com/# ?
